# unable to pass gridview row number to javascript function

Tags: vb.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to pass row number of the gridview to javascript function when checkbox is clicked. Here is checkbox code inside gridview

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkGroup" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TempFaultID")%>'
OnClick="highlightDescription('+<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>+',this.checked);">
</asp:CheckBox>
```

Here is javascript function which this check box trigger

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function highlightDescription(index, state) {
            alert(index + state);
        }    
  </script>
```

Here is the output

[image]

Problem is that I am unable to get row index. Any help !

Answer (score 3):

Use the <%# tag over the entire OnClick function:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkGroup" runat="server"  
OnClick=<%# String.Format("highlightDescription('{0}',this.checked);", CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex) %> >
</asp:CheckBox>
```